Inject Spring Jpa Repositories and Spring Services with Koin
I want to use koin as my main dependency injection library inside a spring boot 3 project, but i don't know how to initialize an instance of a Jpa repository from its interface.
say i have this
interface AccountRepository : JpaRepository<Account, UUID> {
  fun findAccountByEmail(email: String): Account?
  fun findAccountByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String): Account?
}

i want to add it to a singleton like
val repositories = module {
single <AccountRepository> { /* I Don't know what to put here */ }
}

so i can later inject it like
var accountRepo: AccountRepository by inject()

how should i go about doing that?

Found a solution
by passing the EntityManager to the module responsible for creating the repositories from the SpringBoot application like so:
@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val context = runApplication<Application>(*args)
  startKoin {
    modules(
      GenericModules,
      RepositoriesModule(context.getBean(EntityManager::class.java))
    )
  }
}

I was able to do this
val RepositoriesModule: (EntityManager) -> Module = { entityManager ->
  module {
    factory<AccountRepository> {
      JpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager).getRepository(AccountRepository::class.java)
    }

    factory<SessionRepository> {
      JpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager).getRepository(SessionRepository::class.java)
    }
  }
}

then later injected them like:
val accountRepository: AccountRepository by inject(AccountRepository::class.java)

Note: Don't forget to add @Transactional on class level of whatever class is working with these repositories to allow for transactional operations
